# How to bind list of objects to handsontable?

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I have a json object,which contains following data.

```
var myData = [{
        "sNo": "1.0",
        "boqName": "Installation of pole 11 KV",
        "unit": "Nos",
        
        "opportunityBoqOverHeadMasterList": [{
                "opportunityBoqOverHeadMasterId": 14,
                "value": 41.3
            },
            {
                "opportunityBoqOverHeadMasterId": 16,
                "value": 41.3
            },
            {
                "opportunityBoqOverHeadMasterId": 24,
                "value": 100
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "sNo": "2.0",
        "boqName": "Installation of pole 33 KV",
        "unit": "Nos",
       
        "opportunityBoqOverHeadMasterList": [{
                "opportunityBoqOverHeadMasterId": 15,
                "value": 52.92
            },
            {
                "opportunityBoqOverHeadMasterId": 17,
                "value": 52.92
            },
            {
                "opportunityBoqOverHeadMasterId": 25,
                "value": 0
            }
        ]
    },

];
```

}

i need to display the value of opportunityBoqOverHeadMasterList next to the unit cell.
Please help me to display data in handsontable. 
 Please refer jsfiddle for working example https://jsfiddle.net/Umanath16/aty5wfg7/22/

Answer (score 0):

You could try processing the data. Notice below that I changed your `columns` array, create a new `myNewData` variable and create nested loops to format the data.

```
    var columns = [
        {
            "data": "sNo"
        },
        {
            "data": "boqName"
        },
        {
            "data": "unit"
        },
        ,
        {
            "data": "Percentage1"
        },
        {
            "data": "Percentage2"
        },
        {
            "data": "Percentage3"
        }
    ];
```

Change the data obj...

```
    var myNewData = [];
    
    for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
        myNewData.push({
          sNo: myData[i].sNo,
          boqName: myData[i].boqName,
          unit: myData[i].unit
        });
        for (var j = 0; j < myData[i].opportunityBoqOverHeadMasterList.length; j++) {
          myNewData[i]["Percentage"+(j+1)] = myData[i].opportunityBoqOverHeadMasterList[j].value;
        }
    }

    hot = new Handsontable(example, {
        data: myNewData,
        rowHeaders: true,
        columns: columns,
        rowHeaderWidth: 100,
        colWidths: 120,
        colHeaders: colHeaders
    });
}
```

This is just one possible solution. **Please think about possible improvements.** What if the data does not have the same fields? It would need to be dynamic regardless of the field names. Also how would you improve the loops, etc.